# Magento2: Getting Random Javascript errors in console

Tags: magento-2.2.5, requirejs

I am getting error on live website. Everytime i encounter with new error in console.Few of them shown below:

[image]

[image]

Let me know how to solve it.

Comment: Hey,

Did you find solution to this. I have been facing since a month and haven't found anything.